# How to submit spring form in ajax(jquery) with modelAttribute

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp

I am new to Spring MVC.
I have a form like this,

`<form:form action="/myaction.htm" method="post" modelAttribute="myForm" id="formid">` and a controller that returns json

`public @ResponseBody ResultObject doPost(@ModelAttribute("myForm") MyForm myForm){
System.out.println("myform.input");
}`

I am able to submit this using`$("#formid").submit();` and my modelAttribute is working fine, taking values from UI.

my question is, how to submit this form in jquery ajax way?
I tried this,

```
$.ajax({
type:"post",
url:"/myaction.htm",
async: false,
dataType: "json",
success: function(){
alert("success");
}

});
```

the form is submitted but modelAttribute values are nulls, how to include modelAttribute object(object that form is using) while submitting?

Answer (score 54):

You need to post the data.  The way I typically do it is using the following.

```
var str = $("#myForm").serialize();

$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    data:str,
    url:"/myaction.htm",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(){
       alert("success");
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using SpringSecurity with CSRF and I am getting this: Unrecognized token '_csrf': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null'). Any solution to that?

Comment: @zygimantus, you need to the add the action link url to a cSRF filter or else it would not go through.

Comment: OK but if I want to use restful programming and thus, in order to update I need to use the PUT method. How can we make it work in this case?

Answer (score 2):

your ModelAttributes are not populated as you are not passing any params to server.Form data has to be posted to server

`$.post('myaction.htm', $('#formid').serialize())` to send ajax post request.