# Form submission in spring using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, spring, spring-mvc

My Form with spring tags:

```
 <form:form action="save" commandName="user" id="form1">
  <form:input
     .
     .
  <form:select
     .
     .
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form:form>
```

Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody UserEntity dataSave(@ModelAttribute("user") UserEntity user, BindingResult result) {
    userManager.addUser(user);
 return user;
}
```

jquery call:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#form1').submit(function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                url : $("#form1").attr("action"),
                type : "POST",
                success : function(response) {
                 alert("success");
             }
   });
 });
</script>
```

My problem is how to send data from jsp to controller. My form nearly contains 20 Fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957581/how-to-submit-spring-form-in-ajaxjquery-with-modelattribute

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)` to the Spring MVC controller method

eg

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public @ResponseBody UserEntity dataSave(@ModelAttribute("user") UserEntity user, BindingResult result) {
userManager.addUser(user);
return user;
}
```

And also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957581/how-to-submit-spring-form-in-ajaxjquery-with-modelattribute) question.

Answer (score 0):

try this code please

```
$.ajax({
    data:$("#form1").serialize(),
    url : $("#form1").attr("action"),
    type : "POST",
    success : function(response) {
    alert("success");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(event){

        // setup some local variables
        var $form = $(this);
        // let's select and cache all the fields
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
        // serialize the data in the form
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        // let's disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        // fire off the request to /action
        request = $.ajax({
            url: "/app/action",
            type: "post", 
            data: serializedData,
            success: function(response){ 
            // we have the response
            alert(response);
        });

        // callback handler that will be called on success
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // log a message to the console
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
            console.log("Form1 Posted");
        });

        // callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
            // log the error to the console
            console.error(
                "The following error occured: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {
            // reenable the inputs
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });

        // prevent default posting of form
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```